# Is it possible to make a script for certain number of rows in Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with 100k+ rows of data. Is it possible to generate script (inserts) using MSSQL Server 2008 for only last 1000 rows of data? e.g. Tasks > Generate Scripts... is making inserts for all data in the table. This script is very heavy. I know that I can use Query > Results to File. And then write a program to parse results and generate a scripts, but does exist a better way?

Comment: `select top 1000 * into XXX from T order by f desc` then script XXX ?

Comment: That's actually a really smart work around

Comment: Can I script temp table? or just drop that table then?

Comment: Pretty sure temp tables are not listed in the script object UI, so you will need to drop

Comment: yeah, looks like it is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm pretty sure you are out of luck as far as having SSMS doing this for you.  As you said, you can always select the data you want, export it and do some manipulation to create the insert script.  With SQL Server 2008 this could be as simple as

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1, Col2) 
VALUES
(1,'test1'),
(2,'test2'),
(3,'test3'), --997 more
```

It will still take some work but at least you wont have to write the `INSERT INTO MyTable` part 1000  times...